# magento data flow config.xml not loading? Not picking up parse method in overwrite

Tags: magento

My problem is when the data profil runs, its like it isn't picking up covert_adapter_category at all.... I can't seem to eye whats missing... any ideas?

**Output from dataflow import:**

```
Starting profile execution, please wait...
Warning: Please do not close the window during importing/exporting data

Starting Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Adapter_Io :: load
Loaded successfully: "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/import/Categories.csv".
Starting Mage_Dataflow_Model_Convert_Parser_Csv :: parse
Method "parse" not defined in adapter catalog/convert_adapter_category.
Finished profile execution.
```

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Import_Catalog>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Import_Catalog>
  </modules>
  <global>


    <models>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <convert_adapter_category>Import_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Category</convert_adapter_category>
        </rewrite>
   </catalog>

   </models>

  </global>
</config>
```

```
protected $_stores;

/**
 * Category display modes
 */
protected $_displayModes = array( 'PRODUCTS', 'PAGE', 'PRODUCTS_AND_PAGE');

public function parse()
{
    $batchModel = Mage::getSingleton('dataflow/batch');
    /* @var $batchModel Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch */

    $batchImportModel = $batchModel->getBatchImportModel();
    $importIds = $batchImportModel->getIdCollection();

    foreach ($importIds as $importId) {
        //print '<pre>'.memory_get_usage().'</pre>';
        $batchImportModel->load($importId);
        $importData = $batchImportModel->getBatchData();

        $this->saveRow($importData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `config.xml` is set up to rewrite Magento's definition of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Category` with your implementation, `Import_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Category`.  Unfortunately the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Category` doesn't actually exist in Magento, as far as I can see.

I suggest you change your `config.xml` to define your own class prefixes for your models, like the following:

```
<config>
    ...
    <global>
        <models>
            <customimport>
                <class>Import_Catalog_Model</class>
            </customimport>
        </models>
    </global>
    ...
</config>
```

Then edit your Dataflow profile to use the adapter called `customimport/convert_adapter_category`, after you've implemented the logic.

Comment: Right on the money. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Don't panic just flush the cache and run the profile again. This should fix the issue.